# Flutter Could not resolve project :shared_preferences Required by: project :shared_preferences

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have a flutter project which is working fine on another machine. When I cloned the project to my machine I got this error

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration
> ':shared_preferences:debugCompileClasspath'. Could not resolve project
> :shared_preferences_macos. Required by: project :shared_preferences
>
> > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :shared_preferences_macos:
>
> - None of the consumable configurations have attributes. Could not resolve project :shared_preferences_web. Required by: project
>   :shared_preferences
>
> > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :shared_preferences_web:
>
> - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

This is my `flutter doctor -v`

> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows
> [Version 10.0.18362.900], locale en-US)
> • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at C:\flutter
> • Framework revision f139b11009 (3 months ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
> • Engine revision af51afceb8
> • Dart version 2.7.2
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 29.0.2)
> • Android SDK at C:\Users\Administrator.SHADY-LAPTOP\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
> • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
> • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
> • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
> • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
> • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
> • Flutter plugin version 39.0.3
> • Dart plugin version 191.8423
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
>
> [√] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
> • VS Code at C:\Users\Administrator.SHADY-LAPTOP\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft
> VS Code
> • Flutter extension version 3.7.1
>
> [√] Connected device (1 available)
> • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
>
> • No issues found!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After an extensive search, I noticed that the flutter cache folder seems to be corrupted

I run the command `flutter pub cache repair` and I took a while to download all the cache folder which contains all the packages that you have a cache for.

Finally, the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with some project updates. You can try this if you still havent got an answer...

Put the below code into the pubsec.yaml file ...

shared_preferences: ^0.5.6
url_launcher: ^5.4.0